# Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to make a search function in my angularjs "webapp". When I search in products all works fine, but when I change everything so that it searches into users, i get an error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.

Here's my js:

```
    return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
        return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
        if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
};
});
```

And here's the html that's calling it:

```
<div ng-controller="userCtrl" class="container-app">
<div class="bar">
    <input type="text" class="search" ng-model="searchString" placeholder="Enter your search terms" />
</div>
<div class="searchResultsText">
    <h2>Zoekresultaten: </h2>
</div>
<div class="searchResults" ng-repeat="user in users | searchFor:searchString">
    <a class="normal" href="#">{{user.name}}</a>
</div>
```

it does show me the list of users, just as soon as I start typing in the search bar it gives me the error.

when I use the exact same function, with a different controller it works. Here are the 2 controllers:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get(apiUrl + "product/list")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.products = response;
    });
});

app.controller('userCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get(apiUrl + "user/list")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response;
    });
});
```

so basically customerCtrl works fine, but when i change values to userCtrl it stops working.

any suggestions?

Comment: your searchString could be null

Comment: How can it be null? it's the exact same function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely `item.title` is at least once undefined.

```
return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
        return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
        if(
            angular.isDefined(item.title) && 
            item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1
        ){
            result.push(item);
        }
    });
    return result;
};
```

Comment: this fixes the error, except that it doesn't give results back

Comment: ah, in that case, put a `console.log(item);` in the loop to check what is returned, because the item doesn't have a title-attribute. :)

Comment: you are the man, I should read every line of code out loud...thanks it works.